# Is there an image viewer that will save zoom settings across images/folders or use 100% as default?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

It seems to me all the image viewers use a fit to screen approach that zooms out the images... I can set the zoom to 100%, but as soon as I switch images I have to do it again. I'd rather not have it that way.

This seems like something simple to do, is there a viewer that does it by default?

Comment: irfanview.  lots of people use it in linux

Comment: Still have this problem in 2020 with the stock Ubuntu image viewer. It's like people who make the tools never use them themselves. For example you want to quickly compare two photos, zoom in, switch to the other, BAM its zoomed out max again..

Answer (score 5):

## qiv

The answer is `qiv`:

```
qiv -W zoom-percentage image1 image2 ...
```

See http://spiegl.de/qiv/.

Comment: This is a great tool and very efficient with a mouse! Scroll wheel to view next/previous pic, back and forward buttons for zoom levels. -X is a nice bonus too for multi monitor users! Good stuff :)

Comment: Additionally, instead of providing the image names separately you can just provide the folder name `qiv -W zoom-percent foldername` or ask it to display images recursively with -u option: `qiv -u foldername -W zoom-percent`

Answer (score 2):

### feh

[feh](http://feh.finalrewind.org/) is a text-based image viewer. This means it has no graphical user interface. You can open a terminal and type `feh --zoom 100 example.jpg`. The software will zoom this image to 100%. You can also leave the filename empty. Feh will walk through the actual directory and show every image.

### Gimp

[Gimp](http://gimp.org/) does not open a file at 100% zoom every time. But you can open an image and immediately press <kbd>1</kbd>. This will zoom the image to 100%.

### ImageMagick

The software `display` from ImageMagick is also text-based. Use `display example.jpg` to open an image with 100% zoom (programm does it by default).

Answer (score 1):

Try [gthumb](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gthumb/) , after installing go to `Edit > preferences > Viewer column > After loading an image >>` select `Set to actual size .`

Also supports lots of extensions.